# Kotlin reflection recursively

Tags: kotlin, reflection

Let's say I have a data class:

```
data class AnotherDataClass(
    val property: String,
    @KYC
    val annotatedProperty: String
)
```

And I want to retrieve all fields with a certain annotation. I do this:

```
anotherDataClass::class.memberProperties.filter {
     it.findAnnotation<KYC>() != null
}
```

It works fine.

What if I want to retrieve all fields from classes defined within my class containing this variable like the example below?

```
data class DataClass(
    val other: String,
    @KYC
    val otherAnnotated: String
)

data class AnotherDataClass(
    val property: String,
    @KYC
    val annotatedProperty: String,
    val dataClass: DataClass
)
```

Is it possible to check the annotations recursively?

Comment: I'm fairly sure there is no way to retrieve all the classes that reference instances of a specific class. However, if all the classes that use that annotation are defined within the same class, you could use that class's `MyClass::class.nestedClasses` property to get them and iterate through them to find their properties with that annotation.

Comment: @Tenfour04 nestedClasses returns an empty array for the current example :(

Comment: This works for me, but not in the Playground. You'll have to copy-paste it into an IDE since Kotlin Playground doesn't have full reflection features. https://pl.kotl.in/jt6hFMIuM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed possible. The simplest way to think about it is that you want to check every property of this class AND every property of every class that the properties of this class are an instance of. It can be done like this:

```
fun KClass<*>.findAllPropertiesWithKycAnnotation(): List<KProperty<*>> {
    memberProperties.filter {
        it.hasAnnotation<KYC>()
    } + memberProperties.mapNotNull { (it.returnType.classifier as? KClass<*>)?.findAllPropertiesWithKycAnnotation() }.flatten()
}
```

(This is quick and dirty code, there definitely is a more performant way to write this. It all depends on how performance-critical this function is)